# Android Espresso and multiple buildTypes in gradle file cause "Class not found" error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I use Espresso for UI testing and I have multiple buildTypes in gradle file. After recording espresso test, when I'm trying to run test it throws `Class not found:[package name]` error:

> Process finished with exit code 1
>   Class not found: "com.example.myapp.SplashActivityTest"Empty test suite.

This is my gradle file content buildType:

```
   buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug


    }
    development {
        initWith debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "DEV_My App"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://192.168.100.124:8080/"'

    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you running the tests?  Command line or from Android Studio?  If command line what exactly are you running?

Comment: @dweebo From android Studio.

Comment: Maybe try running from command line and see what error you get?  We have a project with multiple build types and espresso tests.  ./gradlew clean connectedDebugAndroidTest or ./gradlew clean connectedDevelopmentAndroidTest